# Spring Security web app can't remove auto login

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to remove the login that is required after every time I start the app. I go to `localhost:3306` and it redirects me to the `/login`. I will have a login button on the webpage but I cannot get to that because this is in the way.

I tried this but it still wants me to login when the app starts.

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/profile").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/profile")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll();
}
```

Comment: What URL do you call? Also show your full configuration class. Did you annotate your class with the neccessary annotations?

Answer (score 0):

try this in your file application.properties...

```
security.basic.enabled=false
```

I dont know your project but you can try disable formLogin in your security configuration too...

```
http.formLogin().disable()
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

To disable security you must try the following lines in your

> application.properties

```
security.basic.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false
```